# Design strategies for class libraries that span Javascript and C#

Tags: client-side, server-side, class-library

I'm implementing some objects which will have about an equal amount of richness on both the client-side and server side.

In this particular case, I'll be building a (hopefully) little class library to deal with search tokens.  So as a pseudo-code example, I'll want to be able to do the equivalent of the following in both Javascript and on the server (C# in my case).

```
s = new SearchTokenList();
s.Add(new SearchToken(field, value, negation));
```

What design strategies will help avoid creating a big ball of mud for a library which must span C# and Javascript?

Update:  Looking for more of strategies than mechanics.  But I'll take any guidance I can get from those who have previously done similar things.

Comment: Hmmmmm. Hypothetically? Interface to hell. Do your utmost to separate them, you want complimentary not bound ideally. If you're inevitably doing client-server communication, get that right first. I'm thinking mediator and/or observer based.

Comment: What I'm looking for is something along the lines of what Annakata was getting at.  I'm happy to help clarify the question if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at Script# by Nikhil Kothari, might help you out. It is a C# to JavaScript compiler.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should check out my C# to JavaScript compiler out at http://jsc.sourceforge.net/

Unlike Script# my jsc compiler works on MSIL level.

WPF Example: [AvalonExampleGallery](http://jsc.sourceforge.net/examples/avalon/AvalonExampleGalleryDocument.htm)
[image]

Contact me if you have any specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

If performance is not critical, you could load the data in JSON or XML and pass it back to server-side and do the processing. I think WCF can generate JavaScript interface out of the box. See [.NET by Example: Calling a WCF service from Javascript](http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2008/02/calling-wcf-service-from-javascript.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run some Javascript code on your .NET server using Microsoft's [JScript.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bf5fs13.aspx) -- compile it with `/target:library` and make sure it's CLS-compliant and that you declare that fact with

```
[assembly:System.CLSCompliant(true)]
```

or other variants of [CLS compliance declarations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.clscompliantattribute(VS.71).aspx). Once you've gotten this to work, you could run (a bit of) JS code on both the server (calling it from C#) and the client (calling it from other JS) and more easily ensure equal functionality on both sides.